# Ground mesh under the capacitive touch pad

Tags: pcb-design, capacitive

I am going replicate a circuit basing from [adafruit AT42QT10xx](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-capacitive-touch-sensor-breakouts/downloads), I will be using the AT42QT1010 variant.

[image]

The touch pad is the blue pad bottom layer, but there is this mesh on the top layer after i traced it, is connected to ground.

What is the purpose of this mesh? Does it have to be a mesh? Will filling it with a ground plane be better? Will placing the components directly above the pad okay too?

My hypothesis is it to prevent "touches" from the bottom, I do not own one of these modules so i unfortunately cant test it.

Comment: Are you sure it is not supposed to be operated from the top? My guess would be, since the top copper (red) is a mesh and not solid, placing your finger on it would directly increase the capacitance of the top mesh as seen from the bottom (blue) copper, plus body capacitance through skin resistance. If the top copper were solid, touching it would only add the entire body's capacitance through skin resistance, and do nothing as far as the blue pad is concerned.

Comment: @rdtsc [video](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1374) from adafruit's page did show that it was operated from the bottom

Comment: @rdtsc so a solid copper would mean no signal and a mesh would mean that there might be little capacitance that will pass through which could be enough to give a signal?

Comment: Hmmm. Reading the datasheet, it is not clear exactly what role the mesh serves. It may have been meshed to reduce capacitance. But it is clear that the bottom (solid pad side) is the active side. For $6, it would be easiest to buy one and experiment with it. Scrape off some of the resist around the mesh and solder on a piece of copper foil to make the ground solid and see how that affects operation. I don't think it's going to be very sensitive from the top regardless. You could faraday-shield the top if necessary by adding an insulating sheet and grounded metal cover (it will re-calibrate.)

Comment: i did fround a [guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/AN2934-Capacitive-Touch-Sensor-Design-Guide-00002934A.pdf) on capacitive sensor design and it would seem to be a rear shield and a better solution for a ground plane because _A rear ground plane may significantly reduce the sensitivity of the touch sensors, as the DC ground
attracts the electric field emitted by the touch sensor electrode_

Comment: unfortunetly they are not available in my area, im not to keen of spending 30$ shipping for a 6$.

Comment: If you are are going to re-create this PCB and populate it yourself, how about making several with different mesh geometries for testing? [OSHPark](https://oshpark.com) and [JLCPCB](https://jlcpcb.com) might ship worldwide for free. The datasheet isn't very clear about `Cs` / `Cx` and how these apply to a meshed ground plane... some experimentation may be in order.

Comment: @rdtsc yes yes that is what is really going to happen, i will also be testing all other parts of my system. I have been using JLCPCB but your recommendation OSHPark seems nice too, the offer flex violet mask and already gold plated, will definetly bookmark it for the final product